# C to PHP password encrypt (reversed)

Tags: php, c, encode

I have a windows application that encrypts user passwords using a reverse of this C code (the below decodes):

```
static void PasswordDecode(char * szPassword)
{
char szEncode[1024];
char strDecodePass[_MAX_BUF_LEN + 1]={""}, strPass[_MAX_BUF_LEN + 1]={""};
strcpy(strDecodePass, szPassword);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(strDecodePass)/3; i ++)
{
char szCode[_MAX_BUF_LEN + 1];
strcpy(szCode, strDecodePass + i * 3);
szCode[3] = 0;
int nCode = atoi(szCode);
nCode = 999 - nCode;
sprintf(szEncode, "%c", nCode);
strcat(strPass, szEncode);
}

strcpy(szPassword, strPass);

return;
};
```

What I'm looking for is the ability to encode passwords using this algorithm (but with PHP) so that I can import user accounts into the application.

Can anyone help?

TIA
Jim

Comment: Is it a local installation of PHP or a remote? If it's local, you'll probably have access to `exec()`, and you can just call a program like from the command line. If it's a hosted installation, you probably don't have access to `exec()` for obvious reasons.

Comment: It is a local install of php, but the application I'm referring to isn't a password encrypter but a full program that has its own integrated user management system. It saves the user account details to an ini file which is what I'm trying to use PHP to write to (so I can make a web interface). HTH

Comment: You have access to this code though: wrap it into a simple executable that takes the password as a command line argument.
EDIT: Forgot for a moment you're trying to encode - but if you have access to the code that encodes, just do the same thing.

Comment: Good idea, though it would be nicer to just keep it inside PHP. Regardless though I've only got the decode code unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
function PasswordEncode($str)
{
    $enc = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $enc .= sprintf("%03d", 999 - ord(substr($str, $i)));
    }
    return $enc;
}
```

And, just for kicks:

```
function PasswordDecode($str)
{
    $dec = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i += 3) {
        $dec .= chr(999 - substr($str, $i, 3));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

As an aside, calling this "encryption" is a wild exaggeration. It's utterly insecure and probably would take about five minutes to figure out just by looking at the encoded passwords.